# ByteBuddy generic method return cast to concrete type

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I am trying to use byte buddy to work with protobuf data and having a hard time with the generic extensions APIs.

```
DynamicType.Builder<?> addSetter(final Class<? extends Message> container,
                                 final GeneratedExtension<?, ?> extension,
                                 final DynamicType.Builder<?> builder) throws NoSuchMethodException {
Method toBuilderMethod = container.getMethod("toBuilder");
Class<?> messageBuilderType = toBuilderMethod.getReturnType();

// generic return type is com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage.ExtendableBuilder
Method setterMethod = messageBuilderType.getMethod("setExtension", GeneratedExtension.class, Object.class);
Method buildMethod = messageBuilderType.getMethod("build");

MethodCall toBuilder = invoke(toBuilderMethod).onArgument(0);
MethodCall setit = invoke(setterMethod).onMethodCall(toBuilder).with(extension).withArgument(1);
MethodCall body = invoke(buildMethod).onMethodCall(setit) ;

return builder.method(named("set0")).intercept(body);
```

Here is the code from protobuf

```
public abstract static class ExtendableBuilder<
        MessageType extends ExtendableMessage,
        BuilderType extends ExtendableBuilder>
      extends Builder<BuilderType>
...
public final <Type> BuilderType setExtension(
        final GeneratedExtension<MessageType, List<Type>> extension,
        final int index, final Type value) {
...
```

Is there any way to change the return type of setit so I can get it to be the builder type messageBuilderType?  I can't find a way to explicitly add a cast and can't find a API to override method return.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the type information being present, this is not possible. You can either create a generic representation of the method as a `MethodDescription` to make the static type compatible. As an easier solution, you can just configure add

```
withAssigner(Assigner.DEFAULT, Assigner.Typing.DYNAMIC)
```

where Byte Buddy simply casts the generic type which would be the consequence of a generic assignment, too.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for now replying in so long.  I added this to body and seems to do the trick.